# Count rows against to SQL server (2005) table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I have a simple question with two options to get count of rows in a SQL server (2005). I am using VS 2005.  There are two options to get the count:

```
SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE dt >= startDt AND dt < endDt;;
```

I get a list of ids from above call in cache and then I get count by List.Count. Another option is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE dt >= startDt AND dt < endDt;
```

The above call will get the count directly. The issue is that I had several cases of exceptions with the second method: timeout. What I found is that the table1 is too big with millions of data. When I used the first option, it seems OK.

I am confused by the fact that Count(*) takes more time than getting all the rows(is that true?). Not sure if the aggregation call with Count(*) would cause SQL server to create temporary table or cache on server side and it would result in slow performance when table is too big?  I am not sure what is the best way to get the count?

Answer (score 1):

You should [add an index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190197%28SQL.90%29.aspx)  on the column `dt`, then it should be very fast.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Table1_dt ON Table1 (dt)
```

Creating the index may take a long time if you have many rows (and I assume you do).

Answer (score 1):

Put indexes on your `dt` field and use `COUNT(id)` (this assumes id is set as NOT NULL)

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Table1 WHERE dt >= startDt AND dt < endDt;
```

Also, `COUNT(id)` vs `COUNT(*)` shouldn't really matter in your case.

Comment: Between is not the same as >= and <. it is >= and <= ..you will get the midnight value of the right range. Take a look at http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql- why it is not smart to use between with dates

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do this

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Table1 WHERE dt >= startDt AND dt < endDt;
```

just remember that COUNT(id) doesn't count NULLS while COUNT(*)  does

do you have an index on the columns in your WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

As Mark suggests, add an index and then use the COUNT(*). You're transferring a HUGE amount of data in option 1 just to count it and then throw it away.

Comment: On top,

WHERE dt >= startDt AND dt < endDt;; 

should be 

WHERE dt BETWEEN startDT AND endDT

Comment: it should not because between would be WHERE dt >= startDt AND dt <= endDt;  Take a look at http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql- why it is not smart to use between with dates

Comment: I mean it should NOT, between is inclusive